# JQueryUIHelpers does not working on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, iis-7, visual-studio-2013

I'm using jqueryuihelpers to show a JqueryDatePicker on a View, in development enviroment all is working ok, I run project on Visual Studio and works fine. The problem is after publish on IIS. When the site is accessed it shows this error.

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JQueryUIHelpers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 29:     using iTextSharp;
Line 30:     using iTextSharp.text;
Line 31:     using JQueryUIHelpers;
Line 32:     
Line 33:
```

---

Code on my view:

```
@Html. JQueryUI(). DatepickerFor (model => model. Data)
```

Important Data:
Visual Studio: 2013
MVC:5
EntityFramework:6

Comment: Is the JQueryUIHelpers bin being added to the bin folder on publish? You either need to ensure it's being included, or add it globally to the machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was exactly that, I copied the file to the bin folder on IIs and Ready. I don´t know why on the publish process all de .dll files are copied to the server except that. Thanks again

Comment: Problem was solved thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/2961342/andysavage

Answer (score 0):

After copying the JQueryUIHelpers.dll from bin folder of the source and pasting in the bin of the published folder works for me.